# method not defined error in Node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Controller.js**

```
<pre>

    exports.getProducts = function(callback)
    {
      Product.find({},function(err,products)
        {
            if(products === null)
            {
                console.log('Products not available in DB');                   
            }
            if(err) 
            {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err,null);
            }
            else{callback(null,products)};         
        });     
    }
    getProducts(function (err,data){
        if(err){console.error(err);}
        else{console.log(data);}
    });

</pre>
```

**App.js**

```
<pre>  

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var morgan = require('morgan');
    app.use(cors());

    var Product = require('./server/controllers/ProductController');
    Product.save();
    console.log(Product.getProducts());

</pre>
```

I am trying to run getProducts() function from app.js, but it is failing by showing 'getProducts' is not defined
Can anyone tell me the mistake I have done ?

Comment: Is it `Controller.js` or `ProductController.js`?

Comment: ProductController.js

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening. There are multiple issues but we'll go through them.

1. You're requiring the ProductController.js, which **runs all the code in that file**. The first block of your controller sets a function, `getProducts` onto the exports object. The second part of that file attempts to invoke a function, called `getProducts` **which is undefined**. The function you're trying to invoke is defined as `exports.getProducts`, not `getProducts`, which is why you're getting the undefined error. **But this is still wrong. More below**
2. In app.js, you're calling `Product.getProducts()`. This is `exports.getProducts()`. It takes a callback argument, which is not being provided in the call to `getProducts` in `app.js`.

Hope that helps you find a solution, good luck!

Comment: Don't forget that the controller.js file doesn't define `Product` anywhere.